# String substitution using dictionary

Tags: python, string, replace, string-formatting

I am learning python and working on strings to find a better way for string substitution using dictionary

I have a string which contains my custom placeholders as below:

```
placeholder_prefix = '$['
placeholder_suffix = ']'

dict={'key1':'string','key2':placeholders}
msg='This $[key1] contains custom $[key2]'
```

I want the placeholders('prefix-suffix' and 'keys') should be replaced by 'value' from the dictionary as below:

'**This string contains custom placeholders'**

I am able to get message as: 'This [string] contains custom [placeholders]' by writing function:

```
def replace_all(text):
    for key, value in brand_dictionary.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(key, value).replace('$[', '[')        
    return text
```

I can try different replace to remove '$[' and ']' but that could replace any character (like '$','[', ']') contained as a part of message itself(not as part of placeholder). So i want to avoid this and replace only for custom placeholders.

I can think of regular expression(for placeholders) but since my message contains multiple keys so seems it may not be useful?

Is there a better way to do it in python?

Comment: Is this an assignment of some sort that you have to solve this way? Or can't you just make use of "format"? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: `'This {key1} contains custom {key2}'.format(**dict)`

Comment: `dict` shadows the builtin `dict` type.

Comment: I need custom placeholders(for customising some part in a message which is for branding purpose). format does work for %s and i know it works nicely with dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more general way you can use `re.sub` with a proper replace function :

```
>>> d={'key1':'string','key2':'placeholders'}
>>> re.sub(r'\$\[([^\]]*)\]',lambda x:d.get(x.group(1)),msg)
'This string contains custom placeholders'
```

The advantage of using regex is that it refuses to match the placeholder characters within string that doesn't have the expected format!

Or as a simpler way you could use string formatting as following:

```
In [123]: d={'key1':'string','key2':'placeholders'}
     ...: msg='This {key1} contains custom {key2}'
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [124]: msg.format(**d)
Out[124]: 'This string contains custom placeholders'
```

Or instead of using a dictionary if number of your variables is not that big you can have your keys as variables that are accessible in current namespace and then use `f-strings` which is feature introduced since Python-3.6:

```
In [125]: key1='string'
     ...: key2= 'placeholders'
     ...: msg=f'This {key1} contains custom {key2}'
     ...: 

In [126]: msg
Out[126]: 'This string contains custom placeholders'
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what i exactly wanted. Thanks Kasra

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski ;)

Comment: I have tried with same regular expression but was unaware of 'lamda' expression and its usefulness. You can solve a problem, but there is always a best solution!! And in this case got it from Kasra :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dict={key1:'string',key2:placeholders}

msg='This {key1} contains custom {key2}'.format(**dict)
```

Example I ran:

```
>>> msg="hello {a} {b}"
>>> t={"a":"aa","b":"bb"}
>>> msg="hello {a} {b}".format(**t)
>>> msg
'hello aa bb'
```

Comment: don't key1 and key2 need to be string?

Comment: dict={'key1':'string','key2':placeholders}
msg='This {key1} contains custom {key2}'.format(**dict)

Answer (score 2):

Another option includes formatting with string substitution:

```
msg='This %(key1)s contains custom %(key2)s'
dict={'key1':'string','key2':'placeholders'}
print(msg%dict)

>> This string contains custom placeholders
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with changing the placeholders, you can use - `%(key)s` - and the `%` operator to automatically apply the dict at those places.

Exmaple -

```
>>> dict={'key1':'string','key2':'placeholders'}
>>> msg='This %(key1)s contains custom %(key2)s'
>>> print(msg%dict)
This string contains custom placeholders
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of rolling your own, consider using an existing templating library like Mako (http://www.makotemplates.org/).

They already do everything you want, plus a lot of things you haven't thought about yet.

(and yes, they also work for producing non-HTML text)