# Python Library to Substitute Some Texts in a Big Text File

Tags: python, text

Using Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Here is the scenario. There is a large text file called `raw.txt` stored locally with some parameterised text. A small example would be like

```
This letter serves to confirm the employment of {full_name} at {company_name}, at {city_name} with a compensation of {salary} per {period}.
```

and in the python script, I have the corresponding variables, like

```py
full_name:str='John Smith'
company_name:str='Glaxo Inc.'
city_name:str='Houston'
salary:int=8500
period:str='month'
```

So what would be the cleanest way to substitute the parameters with the actual variables.

I hope I am describing the problem clearly, basically, something akin to frontend template rendering, but all inside python, loading the `raw.txt` from a disk file, and generating the output string. I could probably use the f string feature of python, but somehow it does seem a bit clunky. The function signature would be

```py
def text_from_template(raw_text:os.PathLike, 
                        params:Dict[str, Any])->str:
    """Generate the new string based on the template file and dictionary."""
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Note that I am the author of `raw.txt` as well, which means if the template format I showed (used just for demonstration) is not correct/clean, I can rewrite it, but this is the use case.

I can use some third party library from pip, if necessary, with the constraints that

- Free and open source
- Well maintained
- Works on both Ubuntu and windows

Comment: This is what Jinja is made to do. Take a look here for a quick run through: https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use python's [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
s = "This letter serves to confirm the employment of {full_name} at {company_name}, at {city_name} with a compensation of {salary} per {period}."

v = {
    "full_name":'John Smith',
    "company_name":'Glaxo Inc.',
    "city_name":'Houston',
    "salary":8500,
    "period":'month'
}

s.format(**v)
# 'This letter serves to confirm the employment of John Smith at Glaxo Inc., at Houston with a compensation of 8500 per month.'
```

Your strings works as-is. You just need to put your variables in a dict or other mapping.

Comment: dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160989/string-substitution-using-dictionary

Comment: I appreciate that @nick. Why are you leaving a comment rather than voting to closing? It seems you have ample rep to do so.

Comment: It's not a great dupe...